# Why does installing wine (for example) require removing 2GB of good packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I have a situation where:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Results in:

```
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     aglfn apturl apturl-common asymptote-doc biber ca-certificates-java catdoc cdparanoia cdrskin cmake-data context
     ...
 Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
 The following additional packages will be installed:
     fonts-wine libwine-development wine-development wine64-development
 Suggested packages:
     ttf-mscorefonts-installer winbind playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox libwine-gecko-2.47 wine64-development-preloader aria2 tor
 Recommended packages:
     libcapi20-3 libodbc1 libosmesa6 wine32-development
 The following packages will be REMOVED
     appmenu-qt asymptote cdrdao chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra clang clang-6.0 cmake cmake-qt-gui compiz compiz-gnome dvd+rw-tools
     eog evince firefox g++-5 g++-5-multilib g++-9 gcc-5 gcc-5-multilib gcc-9 gcj-5-jre-lib gfortran-5 gnome-sudoku
     ...
 After this operation, 2,032 MB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Why? I don't understand why installing `winetricks` would possibly cause `g++-9` and `spotify-client` (and 2GB of utterly essential applications) to be deleted. Can I not use these packages simultaneously?

EDIT: It has even deleted my `ubuntu-desktop` and `nautilus`

I gained access to wine via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/pp
```

I am on `18.04`

Comment: If you want to keep a package that is scheduled for autoremoval, run `sudo apt install <package_name>` manually. This will tell the system that you want to keep that package installed, and you'll see something that looks like this: `<package> is set to manually installed`. All manually installed programs are not removed automatically.

Comment: As a further note, `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` is out of date; use https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu instead.